# APACHE - images not accessible

Tags: php, apache

I had some static html pages that loaded images fine from an Image folder. I've now implemented APACHE and moved my entire folder to htdocs. Now I'm unable to load the same images. The error I get is:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.24 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

Does anyone have any idea how to grant access?

Comment: check file and folder ownership to ensure the user that apache runs as is able to read those files.

Comment: Please post also the Virtual Host or related site settings.